# Displaying selected listbox item in textbox on seperate form?

Tags: c#, listbox, dataset

I am attempting to take a a selected item in a listbox and have it displayed in a textbox in a different form. I am hoping when I click the button on the MainForm it triggers so the selected item is displayed in the textBox

In my MainForm I have:

```
public static string myListBoxString;

private void lstDictionary_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs  e)
{
     myListBoxString = lstDictionary.SelectedItem.ToString();
}

private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   EditWordForm myEditWordForm = new EditWordForm();
   myEditWordForm.SelectedValue = myListBoxString;
   myEditWordForm.ShowDialog();

   this.dictionaryTableAdapter.Fill(this.dictionaryDataSet.Dictionary);

}
```

In the second form where I am attempting to place the selected word I have:

```
public partial class EditWordForm : Form
{
    public EditWordForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        wordTextBox.Text = MainForm.myListBoxString;            
    }

    public string SelectedValue
    {
        set
        {
           wordTextBox.Text = value;
        }
    }


}
```

edit*

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 using (SqlConnection connection =  new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
 {
     connection.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update dictionary set word=@word", connection);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", wordTextBox.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Now that I am able to edit the word I would like to save it to the database. Currently when it saves it replaces all 10 words with the new one as opposed to the one specific entry.
From what I have read and looked up it seems like this code should work but thus far it just displays an empty field in the text box after running the application. The only thing I can think of is that I am using a dataset to populate the initial listbox and that is throwing it off? Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: How is your EditWordForm accessing your MainForm? Should it be passed in the constructor and accessed as a property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your EditWordForm add a property called SelectedValue

```
public string SelectedValue
{
     set
     {
          wordTextBox.Text = value;
     }
}
```

From your main form set this property before showing the Form.

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   EditWordForm myEditWordForm = new EditWordForm();
   myEditForm.SelectedValue = lstDictionary.GetItemText(lstDictionary.SelectedItem);

   myEditWordForm.ShowDialog();

   this.dictionaryTableAdapter.Fill(this.dictionaryDataSet.Dictionary);

}
```

Comment: I showed the edit of the editwordform above but it still displays an empty textbox field when i run it

Comment: @John Have you also set myEditForm.SelectedValue = myListBoxString in your main form, just before ShowDialog?

Comment: Yes I added that part aswell

Comment: @John Can you try myEditForm.SelectedValue = lstDictionary.SelectedItem.ToString()

Comment: It displayed "System.Data.DataRowView" in the textbox as opposed to the word I have selected "apple"

Comment: @John To get the display text you can do this myEditForm.SelectedValue = lstDictionary.GetItemText(lstDictionary.SelectedItem)

Comment: Ah yes that worked! I have one last question though. When the word displays in the textbox and I edit it say change the word to "orange," will it save to the database as the new word?

Comment: @John No that wont work automatically, you will have to write the code to do so on the Save click of the Form. If this solved your issue, do not forget to mark as the answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I also made an edit about saving the word properly if you have any insight on that.

Comment: @John It would be easier if you added that as a different question.